# Fix horizontal space before lists in LTR context when text direction change within frame

Tags: beamer, luatex, lists, babel, right-to-left

Consider this example, why space before list is not the same in the two cases and how to fix it when I change text direction within frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Text}
\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur inside frame 

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item 
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur outside frame 
\begin{frame}{}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item 
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**Update**

The answer from @DavidPurton work fine but with a frame title  the problem occur in the second frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Text}
\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur inside frame

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item 
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur outside frame 
\begin{frame}{Text}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item 
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The short answer is: `\parshape` (used by `list`) is severely broken in `luatex`. The long answer is..., well, there in no long answer yet, but as used by `babel` it seems to work in the main vertical list, but only sometimes inside `\vbox`’es (eg, frames or minipages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

babel sets the wrong `\shapemode`. Imho if you want to change a whole frame you should change the `\pagedir` too:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Text}
\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur inside frame

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur inside frame

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur outside frame
\pagedir TLT %%added 
\begin{frame}{Text}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/13 .

Comment: Thanks @JavierBezos awaiting for a fix of the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly why this happens, but you need to include `layout=lists`.

From the `babel` manual, §1.21:

> **lists** required in `xetex` and `pdftex`, but only in multilingual documents in luatex.

And since you are switching from RTL to LTR, I take it you need this option. Seems to work anyway.

So try:

```
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists]{babel}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a workaround which test `pardir` at the beginning of frame and compare it with `pardir` at beginning of list, if they differ we add `\shapemode=2` at list body begin.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\newcounter{beginframepardir}

\makeatletter
\let\oldframe\frame
\def\frame{\setcounter{beginframepardir}{\bbl@getluadir{par}}
% 0 for TLT 1 for TRT 
\oldframe}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\ifnum\value{beginframepardir}=\bbl@getluadir{par} \else\shapemode=2\fi}

\setbeamertemplate{description body begin}{\ifnum\value{beginframepardir}=\bbl@getluadir{par} \else\shapemode=2\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Text}
\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur inside frame 

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item 
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\selectlanguage{arabic}

\begin{itemize}
\item first item 
\item second item
\item third item
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\selectlanguage{nil} % change to LTR occur outside frame 
\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item 
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}

\selectlanguage{arabic}

\begin{itemize}
\item first item 
\item second item
\item third item
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```